# How do you write Perl statement $age = 25; in BNF or EBNF

Tags: perl, bnf, ebnf

How do I convert the Perl statement $age = 25; to BNF or EBNF grammar?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 4):

I'd write a grammar perhaps something like

```
<statement> ::= <assignment> ";"
<assignment> ::= <lhs> "=" <rhs>
<lhs> ::= <var>
<rhs> ::= <expr>
<var> ::= ("@" | "$" | "%" | "*") <name>
<expr> ::= <var> | <number>
```

That would match a range of Perl-ish assignments (given suitable definitions for `<name>` and `<number>`); not just the one you wrote but also

```perl
$age = 25;
@foo = $bar;
%baz = 9999999;
```

Perl has some syntactic complexities that make it hard to fully check at this level (consider the differences between the expressions `$foo`, `$foo{bar}`, and `$foo->{bar}`) but if you're willing to do a second pass of type checking than it should be a fairly typical statement-and-expression grammar.

Comment: Re "*consider the differences between the expressions `$foo`, `$foo{bar}`, and `$foo->{bar}`*",  That can actually easily handled be BNF. Two of the real problems are that 1) Perl has ambiguities (e.g. `{}` can be both a bare loop or a hash constructor), and 2) earlier parts of the program can affect how later parts are parsed (e.g. prototypes and `BEGIN` blocks).

Comment: `<lhs> "=" <rhs>` should be `<expr> "=" <expr>`. Any expression is allowed on the LHS of an assignment. (An lvalue check performed by the parser may later result in an error, though)

Comment: `;` is more a statement separator than a statement terminator; it's only required if followed by another statement.

Comment: You appear to have attempted to list all sigils, but missed `&`.